# Cut flooring to specific shape

Tags: mesh

I would like to create flooring on the top of the following mesh with the JARCH Vis add-on:

[image: BARCELONA_PAVILION_0004.png]

The creator of the add-on mentions in this video (from 4:04 to 4:56) how to cut the siding (or flooring in my case) to a specific shape.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C0U44GKgTvs

I followed the steps in the video but could not cut the flooring to the mesh.

First I selected all the top faces in "Edit mode."

[image: SCREENSHOT_0001.png]

I then separated the faces from the mesh by hitting P on the keyboard and chose "Selection."

[image: SCREENSHOT_0002.png]

In "Object mode" I did "Origin to geometry".

[image: SCREENSHOT_0003.png]

I then made sure that the rotation is zero and that the scale is one by hitting N on the keyboard.

[image: SCREENSHOT_0004.png]

I then went into "Edit mode" and selected the 10 faces that should make up my flooring. I clicked on "Add Face Group."

[image: SCREENSHOT_0005.png]

Lastly, I went into "Object mode" and clicked on "Convert Object."

[image: SCREENSHOT_0006.png]

This is the result:

[image: SCREENSHOT_0007.png]

The issue is that the flooring is not there where I want it to be. Part of it is outside the mesh, part of it is inside the mesh.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.